# Android java: draw image of a sine waveform

Tags: java, android, draw, trigonometry, sine-wave

How to draw an image (of any type, png, jpg, bmp etc) of a Sine wave knowing frequency with `amplitude = 1`?

Example:

[image: sine wave: amplitude over time]

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `AndroidPlot`. Firstly add it to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.androidplot:androidplot-core:1.4.0"
}
```

Add an `XYPlot` to your layout and then start by amending the [following example](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/demoapp/src/main/java/com/androidplot/demos/DynamicXYPlotActivity.java)

More specifically have a look at:

```
   public Number getY(int series, int index) {
        if (index >= SAMPLE_SIZE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        double angle = (index + (phase))/FREQUENCY;
        double amp = sinAmp * Math.sin(angle);
        switch (series) {
            case SINE1:
                return amp;
            case SINE2:
                return -amp;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

And try changing `sinAmp` to your desired value.

Comment: That's give me coords, but now, how to draw it? Can show me an example code?

Comment: @Northumber Have a look at the link I posted